# "RPC executor service threw an error" when signing in with Google Account on Samsung Galaxy Note 8

Tags: google-account, samsung-galaxy-note-8, setup-wizard

I had a Samsung Galaxy Note 8 I purchased a few years ago. I had a GM seizure and my access code was long on my device. So, I figured since I only used the device for a little longer than two weeks, I would just factory reset it as I had my Google emails written down in my book along with other logins for stuff and their passwords.

So, now, when I go to boot up my device, I choose my language, then agree to terms, and select to use my Google account used with the device instead of my password. I enter it in, then enter its password. Then I received

> RPC executor service threw an error!

Even though it's the right Google account for the device. I can log into it on other devices and log into its backup email too.

I'm not a tech guy. I need help. How to fix this issue?

Comment: After a factory reset the Google Play Services are also reset to the version included in the firmware (which means the current version can be multiple years old). After a factory reset keep the phone on Wifi and wait a few hours. Then Play Services should update itself to latest version. Alternatively you can try to manually download Play Services from a third party site (apkmirror, akpure, ..) and update it.

Comment: So I should factory reset it completely again? Then let it sit on at the start up screen where it asks what language I want to pick the "lets go page'? After that it asks the terms and conditions page ,where if you agree and press next it goes To bring your old data by wireless cable or skip for now. After that press next it asks for a WiFi connection where it checks for updates and brings me to the password or use Google account instead and that's when when my posted problem happens....

Comment: Also how would I manually download play services from a third party if I can't even get into the phone?

Comment: Adding the Google account is optional you can skip it and add your account later.

Comment: It won't let me skip it because the phone had a pass code that I put on it. So it gives me two choices enter the pass code or enter the Google account associated with the phone but when I enter the account I get the RPC executor threw an error. This phone was only used for like two weeks. When I was in the middle of moving and once got to NH couldn't get in with a new prescription Prescriber so I came off 4 anti anxiety, anti PTSD , anti depression, anti seizure meds and had a grand maul seizure due to it. I didn't yet write my new phone's pass code down so here I am...

Comment: I was currently using a cheap phone for my daily uses some Motorola. But, thanks to my yellow naped Amazon parrot biting the phone in the 5minutes of me leaving the room made the phone unusable. So I figured I would once again try the phone I purchased for a little over1k at the time when it was new. But the few people I've talked to like phone fix stores say its a software issue an that they can't do anything. Now I know this can be fixed as it happens on computers and other phones and from what I've read they all got it fixed.  But I haven't figured out how yet....